# How do I print out a list of objects?

Tags: python, object

I have been trying to get my objects to be printed out as list. The list is the inventory. It should be printed out by typing i. But I only an error that shows there objects in a list that can't be printed. I keep getting an error. Please can you help me?

```
def play():

    while True:
        Action_input = get_player_action()

        if Action_input in  ["n","North"]:
            print("Go North")
        elif Action_input in ["s","South"]:
            print("Go South")
        elif Action_input in ["e","East"]:
            print("Go East")
        elif Action_input in ["w","West"]:
            print("Go West")
        elif Action_input in ["i","I"]:
           print("Inventory")
           for i in inventory:
               print(inventory)
        else:
            print("Not an availble direction. Use only n,e,w,s,North,South,East, or West")

class Resources:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.health = health

    def __str__(self):
        return " Name: " + self.name + "Description: " + str(self.description) + " Damage: " + str(self.damage)

class bread(Resources):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "bread"
        self.description = "A kind of food that is cheap and nice."
        self.health = 4


class pako(Resources):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "pako"
        self.description = "A long piece of wood that can be used as a weapon"
        self.damage = 10

class punch(Resources):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "punch"
        self.description = "Using the fist to strike"
        self.damage = 6

class owo(Resources):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "owo"
        self.description = "What you use to buy goods or services"
        self.value = 10


def get_player_action():
    return input("What is your move?")


def best_attack_move(inventory):
    Max_Attack = 0
    Best_attack_move = None
    for item in inventory:
        if item.damage > Max_Attack:
            Best_attack_move = item
            Max_Attack = item.damage

    return Best_attack_move


inventory = [bread(),pako(),punch(),owo()]

play()
```

Error:

What is your move?i
Inventory
[<**main**.bread object at 0x02ADC418>, <**main**.pako object at 0x02ADC448>, <**main**.punch object at 0x02ADC478>, <**main**.owo object at 0x02ADC4A8>]
[<**main**.bread object at 0x02ADC418>, <**main**.pako object at 0x02ADC448>, <**main**.punch object at 0x02ADC478>, <**main**.owo object at 0x02ADC4A8>]
[<**main**.bread object at 0x02ADC418>, <**main**.pako object at 0x02ADC448>, <**main**.punch object at 0x02ADC478>, <**main**.owo object at 0x02ADC4A8>]
[<**main**.bread object at 0x02ADC418>, <**main**.pako object at 0x02ADC448>, <**main**.punch object at 0x02ADC478>, <**main**.owo object at 0x02ADC4A8>]
What is your move?

Comment: Posting the error too will help answering your question

Comment: Hi, try to do this: ```inventory = [bread,pako,punch,owo]``` by removing ```()``` and check if you are getting expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple solution to your problem is in for loop.

```
elif Action_input in ["i","I"]:
       print("Inventory")
       for i in inventory:
           print(i)
```

Replace inventory by i. also there are few errors as described below.

In bread class

```
class bread(Resources):
def __init__(self):
    self.name = "bread"
    self.description = "A kind of food that is cheap and nice."
    self.health = 4
```

replace self.health by self.damage

and same for owo class

```
class owo(Resources):
def __init__(self):
    self.name = "owo"
    self.description = "What you use to buy goods or services"
    self.damage = 10
```

replace self.value by above

Your final code should look alike

```
def play():

while True:
    Action_input = get_player_action()

    if Action_input in  ["n","North"]:
        print("Go North")
    elif Action_input in ["s","South"]:
        print("Go South")
    elif Action_input in ["e","East"]:
        print("Go East")
    elif Action_input in ["w","West"]:
        print("Go West")
    elif Action_input in ["i","I"]:
       print("Inventory")
       for i in inventory:
           print(i)
    else:
        print("Not an availble direction. Use only n,e,w,s,North,South,East, or West")

class Resources:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.health = health

    def __str__(self):
        return " Name: " + self.name + "\n Description: " + str(self.description) + "\n Damage: " + str(self.damage)

class bread(Resources):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "bread"
        self.description = "A kind of food that is cheap and nice."
        self.damage = 4


class pako(Resources):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "pako"
        self.description = "A long piece of wood that can be used as a weapon"
        self.damage = 10

class punch(Resources):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "punch"
        self.description = "Using the fist to strike"
        self.damage = 6

class owo(Resources):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "owo"
        self.description = "What you use to buy goods or services"
        self.damage = 10


def get_player_action():
    return input("What is your move?")


def best_attack_move(inventory):
    Max_Attack = 0
    Best_attack_move = None
    for item in inventory:
        if item.damage > Max_Attack:
            Best_attack_move = item
            Max_Attack = item.damage

    return Best_attack_move


inventory = [bread(),pako(),punch(),owo()]

play()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put every instance of the `inventory` variable inside `str()`, and also.

```
 inventory = [str(bread()),str(pako()),str(punch()),str(owo())]
```

(By the way, the `bread` and `owo` have no damage attribute, so you will get an error about it)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yuval.R
I realised I was trying to have weapons that would give damage and food that would give health. 
But, I did not write the code to do that.